# Excluding array if it contains string

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

wonder if I can get another pair of eyes on this.

*Use case; grabbing DNS records from zone file in order to run shell_exec to import them into another platform.*

I am trying to grab all types of DNS records from a zone file, A record, CNAME, TXT, MX etc. I am doing well so far in that I have managed to do CNAME, TXT and MX records.

I am stuck on the A record. Unfortunately, as I am searching each line of the file for A, this is causing CNAME and the SOA to be returned also. Here's what I have:

```
// Looking for:
$search_a = 'A';

// Read from file
$lines = file("$domain.");

// Check if the line contains A
foreach($lines as $a) {
    if(strpos($a, $search_a) !== false) {
    $a_array = "$a";
    $a_record_output = preg_split('/(.'.$domain.'.|\s)/', $a_array, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($a_record_output);
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain.io.
    [1] => SOA
    [2] => ns1.domain.io.
    [3] => stuff.
    [4] => (64719
    [5] => 14400
    [6] => 7200
    [7] => 2419200
    [8] => 3600)
)
Array
(
    [0] => domain.io.
    [1] => A
    [2] => 8.8.8.8
)
Array
(
    [0] => autodiscover
    [1] => CNAME
    [2] => autodiscover.outlook.com.
)
```

Obviously it is working, however, I need to exclude the SOA and CNAME record as I am only searching for A records.

I need to completely ignore the CNAME and SOA arrays and only return ones which contain just A. Here's an extract from the zone file

```
domain.io.      A   8.8.8.8
www             CNAME domain.io
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: zone file is tab separated file for you? like this: example.com.  IN  A     192.0.2.1

Comment: post your initial file contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the second element of the resulting array is `A` and only if it is, continue with your logic. Else, skip the row:

```
if ($a_record_output[1] !== "A") continue;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1WJfc)

It’d probably be better though if you didn’t select the record at all rather than filtering them. You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a word boundary rather than [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for this:

```
if (preg_match("/\b".$search_a."\b/i", $a)) {
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1jMEN)

Comment: Your second version seems perfect to what I need. I didn't even think about adding $search_a into the preg_match. Thank you very much! Saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put your text file into array form, you can just filter with `preg_grep()`.  This is a logical replacement to using `preg_match()` to search in a loop.

```
$search_a = 'A';
var_export(preg_grep('/^[^\t]+\t+'.$search_a.'\t/',file("$domain.")));
```

This matches from the front of each line, one or more non-tab characters, then one or more tab characters, then the needle string, then a tab character to make sure we are making a tight match.

`preg_quote()` may be necessary depending on what characters will be used in `$search`.

...there are a few ways to skin this cat.

---

p.s. your `preg_split()` pattern could use some refinement as well.  If you provide the raw text from the file, I can craft a better one for you.